# How to follow-up without being bothersome?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, follow-up

Recently, I was hired to a retail position.  I was told that I would be getting a call to come to the store in order to complete the rest of the paperwork.  I did not receive that call.  Then I was told again that I would be getting a call, I did not get any call.

I then visited the store and met briefly with the manager who told me to expect February 10th as a training start-date, and that the assistant manager would be calling me today (this was Friday) "for-sure," and he apologised for the hold-up.  I did not get a call (and still haven't).  I am very interested in this job and I am looking forward to it, but the manager seems very stern and like he really doesn't enjoy being badgered.  I don't want to be bothersome, so how should I respectfully go about following-up on all these calls I am supposed to have gotten?

Comment: Also, verify that they have your correct phone number on file!

Answer (score 3):

That they've already told you that you have a job, and to expect training suggests that communicating with them to clarify the organisation/details is a good idea.

It sounds like things a possibly a bit hectic, and they haven't got around to you.

I would ring them, and ask them professionally and politely what they want to do.

'Hi, I was hired by [Joe] and I was told to expect training on February 10 - Is this time still correct, and can I confirm a time and place attend?'.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've signed (and they've signed) the requisite employment contracts, all you have from this store is a verbal agreement to hire you.  You didn't mention which of the forms you've already filled out, and I can't tell from your post whether this is a large chain or a small retailer.

You should protect yourself.

Find out when the assistant manager will next be at the store, and if possible, go there at the beginning of his/her shift to ask about the paperwork.  Be extremely polite and say, "hi, I'm **__ and I was told by __** that you were the right person to speak to regarding finishing my paperwork before the February 10th start of training."  That person will either know about you and help you out, or put you off again.  If they put you off again, ask for a concrete date/time you should come back to fill out the paperwork.  If they're still giving you the brush off at that point, you should look for a different job.  Companies that are serious about hiring have a more proactive and timely approach to dealing with job candidates, and they've typically got someone (or many people) on top of those duties.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way of following up is to contact (in person, email or phone) and ask the person : "Have you had a moment to do XYZ yet?".

This achieves three things. It reminds them of XYZ without implying that they have forgotten about it. Secondly if they have not forgotten but it is languishing at the end of their TODO list this can be a prompt for them to do it immediately, preferably while you are still in contact with them. Thirdly it implies that the only reason that they have not managed to do XYZ is that they are oh so busy with the important stuff that an important person like them needs to do.

In this case I'd go for something like "Have you had a chance to schedule my training yet? The last time we chatted we discussed a possible date of 10 Feb. That is in 3 days time and I'm not sure if I should show up or not?"